# Android - Disable LG Gingerbread RTL Rendering from Right

Tags: android, right-to-left, android-2.3-gingerbread, persian, lg

I have a problem with LG mobile devices with Android 2.3.7. When I open my application which is in Persian Locale (RTL), everything is rendered from right instead of left.

It is true that Persian Text should be rendered from Right, But in this device even layouts are rendered from right instead of left. (However in Samsung and Nexus devices, the rendering is from left)

For example the following screenshot shows that in our menu ListView, icons are moved from right of the text to the left:

[image: Bad Rendering in LG 2.3.7 devices]

One solution can be replacing everything in English Locale, with Persian content. But it's not a standard solution. Is there anybody who knows the solution?

Comment: hi @Saeed Zareian any updates on the issue? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you can try: 
`android:supportsRtl="false"`